# Need a list of WURFL ids of mobile devices sorted by OS. not using "device_os=" of WURFL

Tags: mobile, wurfl

I need to create groups of all mobile devices for each OS.
I want to use the WURFL IDs, and I'm aware that WURFL sometimes specify the device's OS using "device_os=". Unfortunately many mobile devices are missing this property so I can't rely on it.
Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Most, if not all, modern mobile devices in WURFL have the device_os property set, but they inherit it from their parent devices, so you would either need to use the WURFL API to lookup all devices and check their device_os, or you will need to parse to XML file directly, combining the capabilities of each device with the capabilities of their parents, specified in the fall_back XML attribute.  For devices with a blank device_os, the OS is totally proprietary and perhaps completely indistinguishable from the higher-level software on the device.